# Why is accessing a static array reference slower than a non-static array reference

Tags: c#, optimization

Have a look at this snippet:

```
public class StringToggler
{
    static readonly bool[] ToggleableLatinChars = new[]
    {
        // 256 bools here
    };

    readonly bool[] LocalToggleableLatinChars = ToggleableLatinChars;

    public string Toggle(string s)
    {
        // blah blah

        if (LocalToggleableLatinChars[(byte) ch])
        {
            // blah blah
        }

        // blah blah
    }

    // blah blah
}
```

This code is demonstrably quicker (7% ish) in testing than if I used ToggleableLatinChars directly.
(Using a local reference to ToggleableLatinChars in the method is also quicker by the same amount).

This effect is noticed only when compiling for .NET 4.
When compiling for .NET 3.5, I see the opposite effect - using the static array is noticeably quicker. (My machine is an Intel i5 running Windows 7 64-bit and is compiling for x86)

Any idea why?

Update:
Here is a complete code sample which is more akin to Marc's testing sample. Note I am now using static and local variable versions (not member variable any more). Although the difference I see with this is less than I was seeing with my original test code, when compiled for .NET 4, the local version is always faster. You can swap the running order around but Local always wins for me. (Compiling for .NET 3.5 does not do this: it is much faster overall than .NET 4 and static is either faster or the same)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;

internal class Program
{
    const int RepeatCount = 500000;

    const string TestString1_Unicode =          @"?=3.1415926?!! ?a??!#!%# ÜBERGRößEN!!?????? ??????@!e=2.71828182?#!!$@\^i^/!@$";
    const string TestString2_Numbers =          @"p=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510....!!!!";
    const string TestString3_LowerCase =        @"nevr un-den-erstimate ze pauer of stoopid piplz in larg grupp!\*^*/";
    const string TestString4_UpperCase =        @"DUDE, WHY U R HERE?? U SHOULDA BE IN THE MEETING (BLAH-BLAH) $\*o*/$!";

    static void Main()
    {

        RunTestsStaticAccess();
        RunTestsLocalAccess();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void RunTestsLocalAccess()
    {
        StringToggler st = new StringToggler();

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < RepeatCount; i++)
        {
            st.ToggleCase_LocalAccess(TestString1_Unicode);
            st.ToggleCase_LocalAccess(TestString2_Numbers);
            st.ToggleCase_LocalAccess(TestString3_LowerCase);
            st.ToggleCase_LocalAccess(TestString4_UpperCase);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "RunTestsLocalAccess", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    public static void RunTestsStaticAccess()
    {
        StringToggler st = new StringToggler();

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < RepeatCount; i++)
        {
            st.ToggleCase_StaticAccess(TestString1_Unicode);
            st.ToggleCase_StaticAccess(TestString2_Numbers);
            st.ToggleCase_StaticAccess(TestString3_LowerCase);
            st.ToggleCase_StaticAccess(TestString4_UpperCase);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "RunTestsStaticAccess", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    public class StringToggler
    {
        static readonly bool[] ToggleableLatinChars = new[]
        {
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false, false, false, false, false,
            false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,
             true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true, false
        };

        readonly TextInfo textInfo;

        public StringToggler()
        {
            textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
        }

        public StringToggler(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
        }

        public unsafe string ToggleCase_StaticAccess(string s)
        {
            s = string.Copy(s);

            fixed(char* p = s)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    char ch = p[i];

                    if (ch <= 0xff)
                    {
                        if (ToggleableLatinChars[(byte) ch])
                        {
                            p[i] = (char) (ch ^ 0x20);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch))
                        {
                            case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
                                p[i] = textInfo.ToLower(ch);
                                break;

                            case UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter:
                                p[i] = textInfo.ToUpper(ch);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return s;
        }

        public unsafe string ToggleCase_LocalAccess(string s)
        {
            s = string.Copy(s);

            var toggleableLatinChars = ToggleableLatinChars;

            fixed(char* p = s)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    char ch = p[i];

                    if (ch <= 0xff)
                    {
                        if (toggleableLatinChars[(byte) ch])
                        {
                            p[i] = (char) (ch ^ 0x20);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch))
                        {
                            case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
                                p[i] = textInfo.ToLower(ch);
                                break;

                            case UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter:
                                p[i] = textInfo.ToUpper(ch);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you measured this?

Comment: btw, a `char` is 16-bits; and an array indexer wants 32 bits. A `(int)ch` is more appropriate here.

Comment: Can you include the method you used to test?

Comment: a). Are you measuring a sufficient number of iterations to be sure tha any cache-warming effects are eliminated? Run tests for extended persiods. b). can you disassemble the code and have a look? Could be that somehow different pointer sizes are being used in the two cases?

Comment: For a claim like this a code excerpt with a lot of `// blah blah` is not enough.

Comment: The speed test harness is pretty sound: It performs a JIT pass before timing; calculates the overhead of calling back the test delegate; sets the test thread priority to high; collects garbage between passes; calculates mean and std for the whole set and also the same after removing up to 30% of the slowest runs etc.

In this instance I am using 500,000 repeats and 10 timing runs.

Comment: @Marc: In this case the array size is exactly 256 and the array access is only called when ch <= 255 hence the (byte) conversion. Casting to int is superfluous as char is auto-extended anyway. I was using the byte cast hoping that the compiler could work out that a bounds check is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Simon I do not believe that bounds check will be optimised away. It does this for `for` loops on the length, but that's it AFAIK.

Comment: @Marc: You're probably right but it was worth a try since the compilers do some clever stuff these days. (removing it made no difference anyway timingwise)

Comment: @Simon as a side note - did you consider 4 `long` and a few shift `>>` etc operations? Might be faster

Comment: @Marc: Where do you see shifts fitting in? The only alternative I've used instead of the lookup was 
char foo = (char) (ch & ~0x20);

if ((foo >= 0x41 && foo <= 0x5a) || (foo >= 0xc0 && foo <= 0xde && foo != 0xd7))

Comment: @Simon you need 256 bools. An effective way to store that would be to use the bits of 4 x 64-bit integers. Then bool index 17, say, is `((long0 >> 17)&1)!=0`. These 4 longs could be direct fields rather than a de-reference to an array

Comment: @Marc: That would save some space but would it be faster? I'll give it a try. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Simon the CPU can do math like that *very* quickly, all in registers. Especially on a 64-bit CPU/OS It could well be faster than the de-reference, yes. Especially when you consider a null-check, a bounds-check, etc

Comment: Of course, something else it can do very quickly is branch on an integer. Did you try having a switch(ch) with lots of cases?

Comment: It turns out that the shifting has already been tried by someone else and was 5% slower. I don't think switch can be faster than range check I showed in previous comment. Overall I think the code is as fast as it gets. It seems that .NET 4 is slightly slower with a static array access than a local one and much slower (compared to .NET 3.5) for the Unicode stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Simply: it isn't. I don't trust your (not provided) test:

My results:

```
InstanceField: 6035ms
LocalVariable: 5373ms
StaticFieldStaticInitializer: 5364ms
StaticFieldNoInitializer: 5388ms
```

which ties in to what I would expect from additional ldarg0 and ldfld (to get the value from an instance field) rather than the simpler ldsfld (to get the value from a static field) or ldloc0 (to get the value from a local variable).

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new InstanceField().RunTests();
        new LocalVariable().RunTests();
        new StaticFieldStaticInitializer().RunTests();
        new StaticFieldNoInitializer().RunTests();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    class InstanceField
    {
        public bool[] arr= new bool[1024];
        public void RunTests()
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j]) count++;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", GetType().Name, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
    class LocalVariable
    {
        public void RunTests()
        {
            bool[] arr = new bool[1024];
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j]) count++;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", GetType().Name, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
    class StaticFieldStaticInitializer
    {
        public static bool[] arr = new bool[1024];
        public void RunTests()
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j]) count++;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", GetType().Name, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
    class StaticFieldNoInitializer
    {
        public static bool[] arr;
        public void RunTests()
        {                
            arr = new bool[1024];
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j]) count++;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", GetType().Name, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which in assembly is "mov ecx, dword ptr ds:[xxxx]" to get the static array and "mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]" plus "mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+4]" to get the instance array...

Comment: I have just changed the question to clarify the .NET version I was compiling for (.NET 4). When I repeat the test for 3.5 I get the opposite effect.
At first try, I can't reproduce the effect using your code (under either .NET version) but I will try to find out what the difference is.

Comment: I think your code is not near enough to my code to show the effect. Your tests are basically just iterating over the array length which I think is being optimized since it is a recognizable pattern. My code is using each char in the input string as an index into the array. Also your test cases do not replicate the important point: I always have a pre-created static array but accessing it directly proves slower than having a local var (or member variable originally) pointing to the *same* array (for .NET 4).When I change your code to pass in a string and use it static is ~6% slower.

Comment: @Simon which is exactly why it is hard to talk about performance unless you post an example in the first place

Comment: Fair enough :-). I did think  there was just enough information in the original snippet about the static and the 'extra' reference to it but I do find I misjudge the information to provide. Complete example now provided.